# Copying arrays of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

It's been a long since I don't use C language, and this is driving me crazy. I have an array of structs, and I need to create a function which will copy one array to another (I need an exact copy), but I don't know how to define the function call. I guess I need to use pointers, but when I try it gives me an error.

```
struct group{
    int weight;
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
    int width;
    int height;
};

struct group a[4];
struct group b[4];

copySolution(&a, &b);
```

That last declaration send me an error. As I said, it's been a long since programming in C, so I'm a bit lost right now :(

Comment: whats the prototype of copySolution ??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That should do it:

```
memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(a));
```

**EDIT**: By the way: It will save a copy of `a` in `b`.

Comment: You might add a " if(sizeof(b) >= sizeof(a)) ", check as well.

Comment: Fred, yeah, true! In real-world programs that should be done :-)

Comment: Or more likely an assert, since there's usually nothing much a program can do to compensate for the programmer getting it wrong...

Comment: Use memmove() - it is guaranteed to be safe even for overlapping copies, unlike memcpy().

Comment: @onebyone: At least with a conditional you can attemp to fail gracefully as opposed to terminate the application.

Comment: @Jonathan: question says copying "one array to another". So they don't overlap. @Fred: "fail gracefully, or do not fail gracefully. There is no try". Some programmer thinks that array A fits inside array B, when it doesn't. Your program is in a state which you (the programmer of this routine) are certain is the result of a wrong assumption by a programmer. Under such dire circumstances, an assert *is* failing gracefully. Better to stop right now with a diagnostic, than to just keep executing broken code until eventually demons fly out of your nose.

Comment: ... and of course you should consider yourself lucky if the assert actually does anything. If your caller is asking you to do something undefined now, there is every chance that this isn't the first time. The program could be doing anything. If you don't abort, there is every chance that it won't be the last. Just put the process down and back away slowly.

Comment: @SteveJessop Since the sizes are known at compile time, `static_assert()` is a good option here.

Comment: Is it correct to use the pointer operator (&) in this context? aren't `a` and `b` already pointers to the beginning of the array? Shouldn't it be `memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a))`. But since this answer is so old and no one pointed it out, I must be missing something.. and I'm probably just being an idiot right now

Comment: @rboy the pointer to an array (`&a`) and the pointer to the first element (`a`, as arrays decay into pointers to the first element if lvalues) have the same (pointer) value. They however have different types which doesn't matter here as memcpy treats all types the same. I should have gone for `memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a))`, no idea anymore why I didn't but both work here :)

Comment: Well, in the short period I was using C, I've never used `&` on arrays to get their address, I always assumed it's just illegal and it would behave as if you're trying to get a pointer to an address, which doesn't make much sense. Thanks for clarifying this up for me :)

Comment: why the need of `&` when `a` and `b` themselves decay to `*`?

Answer (score 4):

As Johannes Weiß says, `memcpy()` is a good solution.

I just want to point out that you can copy structs like normal types:

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i]; /* copy the whole struct a[i] to b[i] */
}
```

Comment: every compiler I have seen has called memcpy when using '=' when copying structs.

Answer (score 1):

This has a feel of poorly masqueraded homework assignment... Anyway, given the predetermined call format for `copySolution` in the original post, the proper definition of `copySolution` would look as follows

```
void copySolution(struct group (*a)[4], struct group (*b)[4])
{
  /* whatever */
}
```

Now, inside the `copySolution` you can copy the arrays in any way you prefer. Either use a cycle

```
void copySolution(struct group (*a)[4], struct group (*b)[4])
{
  const struct group *pb, *pbe;
  struct group *pa;

  for (pa = *a, pb = *b, pbe = pb + sizeof *b / sizeof **b; 
       pb != pbe; 
       ++pa, ++pb)
    *pa = *pb;
}
```

or use `memcpy` as suggested above

```
void copySolution(struct group (*a)[4], struct group (*b)[4])
{
  memcpy(b, a, sizeof *b);
}
```

Of course, you have to decide first which direction you want your arrays to be copied in. You provided no information, so everyone just jumped to some conclusion.

Comment: It's kind of homework, since it's my final project career :P truly, It's been a while and me an C could never get along each other :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case previous solutions did not work properly! For example,
@Johannes Weiß's solution did not copy "enough" data (it copied about half of the first element).
So in case, somebody needs a solution, that will give you correct results, here it is:

```
int i, n = 50;
struct YourStruct *a, *b;

a = calloc(n, sizeof(*a));
b = malloc(n * sizeof(*b));
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) { 
    // filling a
}

memcpy(b, a, n * sizeof(*a)); // <----- see memcpy here

if (a != NULL) free(a);
a = calloc(n*2, sizeof(*a));

memcpy(a, b, n * sizeof(*b)); // <------ see memcpy here again
```

Some notes, I used calloc for a, because in the '// filling a' part I was doing operations that required initialized data.

Comment: I think I must have.  I’ll remove the misplaced comment.

Answer (score -3):

The compiler has no information about the size of the array after passing them as pointer into a function. So you often need a third parameter: The size of the arrays to copy.

A solution (without any error checking) could be:

```
void copySolution(struct group* a, struct group* b, size_t size) {
    memcpy(a, b, size * sizeof(*a));
}
```

Comment: Not true. The original code passes the arrays as pointers of `struct group (*)[4]` type not as pointers `struct group *` type. With properly declared `copySolution` the array size is embedded in the pointer type. With your definition the original code simply won't compile, not only because of the missing third parameter, but also because the argument type doesn't match the parameter type.

Comment: I'm trying also that, since I need to pass the array to another function, and it says this:

simulated_annealing.c: In function ‘main’:
simulated_annealing.c:39: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘chooseNeighbour’ from incompatible pointer type

The code:

chooseNeighbour(&candidateSolution, nGroups)
void chooseNeighbour(struct group *g[], int size){
 printf("%i\n", g[0]->weight);
}

Comment: @Víctor : Your call is wrong. Should be `chooseNeighbour(candidateSolution, nGroups)`. Note: no `&` operator.

Answer (score -6):

The easiest way is probably

```
 b=a
```

although a solution with `memcpy()` will also work.

Comment: `b=a;` does not work when, as is the case here, `a` and `b` are arrays.

Comment: b=a simply copies the pointer value of a to b, which is not what OP wants

Comment: `b=a` does not work -- arrays are not lvalues in C, so they cannot be assigned like this.

Comment: You could get a pointer to point at the same array with structs, but that is not a copy then.

Comment: @No Name: **get a name!** and that's wrong too. `b` cannot be assigned to since it's an array.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Arrays are *lvalues* in C. Every object that has location in memory is called *lvalue* in C. Arrays are no exception. However, arrays in C are *non-modifiable* lvalues. This is why you can't assign to an array.