# How to move struct array value to another array value on one struct

Tags: c, struct

I want to record my some student information on struct with realloc(memory allocator).When I try to solve this problem ; I will sort the data by given id's but each id has some additional information about whoose id's student. I sort the struct by id but when ı move the each data to another data compiler dont do this. Please could you help me ? Note: I don't mean to move struct to another struct.I just want to move strcut array one element values to another array element value or change theese data position for sorted data

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char name[10];
    char surname[10];
    double quiz1;
    double quiz2;
    double quiz3;
    double midterm;
    double finall;
}STUDENT;

int indis = 0;
void swapInt(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void swapDouble(double *a, double *b)
{
    double temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void str_swap(char const ** str1, char const ** str2)
{
    char const *temp = *str1;
    *str1 = *str2;
    *str2 = temp;
}

void sortSt(STUDENT *st) {
    int i, j, min;
    for (i = 0; i < indis - 1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < indis; j++)
            if (st[j].id < st[min].id) {
                min = j;
                // Swap the found minimum element with the first element
                memcpy()
                swapInt(&st[min].id, &st[i].id);
                str_swap(&st[min].name, &st[i].name);
                swapChar(st[min].surname, st[i].surname);
                swapDouble(&st[min].quiz1, &st[i].quiz1);
                swapDouble(&st[min].quiz2, &st[i].quiz2);
                swapDouble(&st[min].quiz3, &st[i].quiz3);
                swapDouble(&st[min].midterm, &st[i].midterm);
                swapDouble(&st[min].finall, &st[i].finall);
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying arrays of structs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693853/copying-arrays-of-structs-in-c)

Comment: Yes I know this function but strongly I don't mean it. Or I can't use this funciton.I wrote like this memcpy(st[j], st[min], 8);  It is not work.Could you help me? @IgorPavkovic

Comment: Actually main problem is , the program should display the List of students with id name and surname (ordered by student id). How to do this? Idon't want to ask all problem but I give for understanding problem solveing technique.

Comment: Why don't you just swap the students , instead of swapping each field one by one? Copy your `swapInt` function but change `int` to `STUDENT`.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question to my T.A. He answered but the solution is very simple :) 
Like this;

```
void removeStudent(STUDENT *st , int numberOfStudent) {
    int id;
    printf("Please enter id for remove student \n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    for (int i = 0; i < indis; i++)
    {
        if (st[i].id == id) {
            st[i] = st[numberOfStudent];  // this is exactly answer
            printf("%d id's student removed \n", id);
            break;


}
    else if(i==indis) {
        printf("%d id's student not found \n ",id);
    }
}
```

}